# Find all natural numbers $b>3$ such that $1331_b$ is a cube

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all natural numbers $b>3$ such that the number $1331_b$ is the cube of some natural number.

In the notation above, "$1331_b$" means the number $1331$ is in base $b$.

I found that $1b^3+3b^2+3b^1+1b^0$ is $(b+1)^3$, does it means that the thing is a cube for all b>3?

Comment: Your work shows that the thing is a cube for all $b\gt 3$.

Comment: and that this number is b+1.

Comment: Similarly, $(b+1)^4 = b^4+4b^3+6b^2+4b+1$, so $14641_b$ is a fourth power for any base $b > 6$.

Comment: Or put another way, the number is $11_b$.

Comment: Yes, I figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any b, $(b+1)^3= 1*b^3+3*b^2+3*b^1+1*b^0$ so 1331 in base b is always equal to (b+1)^3 for b>3